# How to get name of a file from the link of that file in firebasestorage in flutter dart

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-storage

I am using firebase storage to store files in my flutter app i can get the download link of that file from the firebase storage ,but i want the name of that file after uploaded.what is the way to get it.
it is an sample link of an .mp3 file generated by firebase storage.

```
https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/musicapp-002.appspot.com/o/song%20name%2Calbum%20name%2Cartist%20name%20by%20testing0%40gmail.com.mp3?alt=media&token=213b776c-5563-468a-9724-0f53d75aff90
```

and the file name is  `song name,album name,artist name by testing0@gmail.com` so how to generate the filename from the given firebase storage link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this :

```
String  link = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/musicapp-002.appspot.com/o/song%20name%2Calbum%20name%2Cartist%20name%20by%20testing0%40gmail.com.mp3?alt=media&token=213b776c-5563-468a-9724-0f53d75aff90";

link =  link.split("/")[7];
link = link.replaceAll("%20"," ");
link = link.replaceAll("%2C", ",");
link = link.substring(0, link.indexOf('.mp3'));
link = link.replaceAll("%40", "@");
print(link);
```

Output :

```
song name,album name,artist name by testing0%40gmail.com
```

Comment: thanks! it is perfect with another line of code "link =
                              link.replaceAll("%40", "@");"